# Functional tests require login with devise_token_auth

Tags: authentication, devise, token, rails-api

I am using `devise_auth_token` gem for my user authentication, and I am creating a rails-api that simulates "stackoverflow" site (this site), so my controllers are under the namespace 'api' and some of their actions require the user to be logged in first in order to proceed like (create a question, answer, or vote).

When I use the 'sign_in' method in my 'Questions_controller_test' it returns the id of the given user but '@controller.api_user_signed_in?' returns always false, means no user is already signed in and hence the test fails.

Can anyone give a suggestion to handle this problem, thanks alot.
here is one of my controllers_test

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'devise_token_auth'

class QuestionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @controller = Api::QuestionsController.new

    @current_user = users(:confirmed_email_user)
    @current_user.save!

    @auth_headers = @current_user.create_new_auth_token

    @result = sign_in @current_user

    Ability.new(@current_user)

    @token     = @auth_headers['access-token']
    @client_id = @auth_headers['client']
    @expiry    = @auth_headers['expiry']

    age_token(@current_user, @client_id)

  end
#========================================================
  test 'Get #index' do
    # this test passes
    get :index
    assert_response :ok
    end

    test 'Post #create' do
    # this test fails cause the controller.current_api_user == nil
        post :create , params: {title: 'Q1', description: 'sjdfsdfs'}, headers: @auth_headers, auth_token: @current_user.auth_token
    assert_response :created
    end
end
```

and the test_helper is

```
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'devise'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  def age_token(user, client_id)
    if user.tokens[client_id]
      user.tokens[client_id]['updated_at'] = Time.now - (DeviseTokenAuth.batch_request_buffer_throttle + 50.seconds)
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def expire_token(user, client_id)
    if user.tokens[client_id]
      user.tokens[client_id]['expiry'] = (Time.now - (DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan.to_f + 10.seconds)).to_i
      user.save!
    end
  end

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
      # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
      include Capybara::DSL

      # Reset sessions and driver between tests
      # Use super wherever this method is redefined in your individual test classes
      def teardown
        Capybara.reset_sessions!
        Capybara.use_default_driver
      end
    end

    class ActionController::TestCase

        include Warden::Test::Helpers
    include Devise::TestHelpers

    def setup
        @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end

    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by stubbing the user_sign_in? helper method from devise_auth_token gem

```
 allow(controller).to receive(:ensure_sign_in)
```

"ensure_sign_in" method is a before action that calls the devise_auth_token helper method above"

and its working now :)